# check url is currently at the right location with correctly formatted id

Tags: java, selenium

Say I have a url like this in

```
http://localhost:3300/district/applications/e8533067-e9cd-4888-b4f3-0cdc60a14c40
```

I want to check that the user is a the correct url e.g. `/district/applications/`

And I also check that the last part of the url is a uuid.  I don't want to check the exact value, just that it is a uuid.

I can say:

`assertThat(getDriver().getCurrentUrl(), containsString('/district/applications'));`

An I could get the last part of the url

`String id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

But how can I test it is a uuid or are there any helpers in selenium for this type of thing.

Comment: you can use regex on id. id.matches("/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/") returns true or false for UUID. The regex is to test if the string is UUID or not. matches method is part of string class and it takes a regex and checks if the string matches the pattern or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, do something like this:

```
try{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(someUUID);
    //do something
} catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
    //do whatever you want here if its not a uuid
}
```